# Что представляет из себя пространство между данными объектами?

Tags: css

Привет.

Один вопрос мне не понятен. На примере будет понятно. Создаю блочный элемент `<div></div>` заданного размера и накидываю в него другие элементы `<div> </div>` такого заданного размера, чтобы они вплотную были внутри родителя. Причем все padding и margin обнуляю, хочу, чтобы объекты были "впритирку".  Получаю это то, что на рисунке 1.

Вот стили:

```
.images{    
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px; 
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   display:inline-block;
   border-radius:10px;
}

#container{         
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   width:600px;
   height:600px;
   border:5px solid orange;
   background-color:orange; 
   position:absolute;
   border-radius:10px;;
}
```

Удаляю текстовые объекты-узлы DOM, которые браузер самовольно запихнул между моими дивами. Если их удалить, то дивы будут расположены "бок к боку", как на рисунке 2. Но остается зазор между верхней и нижней "строкой".

Вопросы:

1. Что это за зазор? Все лишние текстовые узлы я убрал. Как убрать этот зазор между "строками"?
2. Зачем браузер запихивает лишние текстовые узлы между моих узлов? Зачем-то же это придумали разработчики.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: стоит так же добавить разметку и стили. По боковым - все подряд идущие пробельные символы в html переходят один пробел, который и показывается между `inline` элементами.

Comment: Для блочных элементов такой проблемы быть не должно. Скорее всего ошибка в применяемых стилях

Comment: разметки конкретной нет и стилей - элемент <div> </div> и десять элементов <div> </div>  внутри него. вопрос общий, такое всегда происходит - это не недоработка конкретного кода. отступы поставил ноль везде, чтобы посмотреть, как объекты себя поведут. хотел квадраты запихать в большой квадрат "западлицо" - чтобы вообще не было никаких зазоров

Comment: Без стилей они бы так не выглядели. Есть какой то код. Показали бы. Мы бы помогли

Comment: нужен конкретный пример разметки и стилей при котором вид получается как на предоставленных картинках.

Comment: спасибо за ответы, вопрос уже решен

Comment: @Dimon, тогда стоит его удалить, в текущем виде он не будет полезен будущим посетителям

Comment: код приведу, чтобы был полезен

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в использовании `display:inline-block`.

Альтернативное решение, использование `display:flex` на контейнере, с настройкой `flex-wrap:wrap`.

```css
.images {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: green;
}
#container {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="images"></div>
  <div class="images"></div>
  <div class="images"></div>
  <div class="images"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы пропал отступ нужно обнулить line-height.

Comment: Спасибо, мне то же самое одновременно сказали на тостере)

Comment: Обычно у родителя задают font-size: 0; и line-height: 0, а потом их переопределяют если нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Мини-игру писал на джаваскрипте и столкнулся с этой проблемой. Хотел, чтобы ячейки игрового поля *примыкали* друг к другу (чтобы не было игрового поля в виде "сот", где ячейки отделены границами). Когда я зделал блочные элементы строчно-блочными, то они имеют как свойства строчных элементов, так и блочных. А у строчных элементов есть понятие "расстояние между строками". Плюс, еще у строчных элементов есть перевод строки это пробел, который визуально тоже может создавать отступ. Оказывается, что есть специальные межстрочные отступы в CSS, которые регулируются свойством line-height CSS. Никогда не слышал про них. Применил line-height:0px, и проблема решилась - зазоры между строк "схлопнулись".

На вторую часть вопроса, а именно

**2. Зачем браузер запихивает лишние текстовые узлы между моих узлов? Зачем-то же это придумали разработчики. я отвечу сам.**

Браузер расценивает любые символы (числа, буквы, пробел, перевод строки, табуляцию…), которые не лежат в элементе, как текстовый узел. В моем документе HTML *все выводится на экран: (кроме служебных элементов), и, когда я ввожу символы какие-то *Вне* служебных элементов, то браузер думает «Ага, он хочется, чтобы я их вывел. Стоп, но они же не внутри элемента, тогда выведу их, как обычный текстовый узел (у которого объектом-прототипом является объект-прототип Text)». Я раньше сталкивался с подобной ситуацией, но не понимал, почему так. Например, я пишу код:

```html
…
<body>
  Привет
  <div>123</div>
…
```

Вот этот текст «Привет» как раз и запихнули в такой объект-узел текстовый. Поэтому «Привет» и вывелся на экран, хотя я думал «Почему он выводится, он же не в элементе?». Но помни, что текст-тексту рознь (про это написано в следующем курсе по JavaScript). У этого объекта-узла «Привет» объект-прототип Text. Если же я создаю джаваскриптом переменную-объект с использованием функции-конструктора String(), то у этого объекта объект–прототип (а значит, свойства и методы совсем другие) совсем другой – String{…}.
То есть, *вcя разметка неслужебной части моего хтмл-документа вместе с символами между самими элементами разметки* (пробел, табуляция, перевод строки…) расценивается браузером как то, *что я хочу вывести на экран*, преобразуется в объекты-узлы дерева DOM (подчеркиваю, что именно объекты-УЗЛЫ – они *выводятся на экран*, а не просто объекты дерева BOM) и *вплетаются* в BOM. Я написал «вплетаются», так как создаются еще и промежуточные объекты-контейнеры («неузлы») – например, если пишу элемент див с id=”first”, а в него кидаю еще два элемента див, то в BOM два *соответствующих* объекта div будут лежать не на первом уровне вложенности, а на *втором* по отношению к первому объекту div – в «более упорядоченном» объекте-посреднике, на который ссылается свойство

```js
document.getElementById(“first”).childNodes;
```

. Плюс, стилевая часть содержимого моего хтмл-документа образует другое дерево – дерево CSSOM, которое также «вплетается» (вкладывается) в BOM. Это дерево объектов, которые *не отображаются* на экране (а помогают понять браузеру, как отобразить объекты-узлы DOM, которые отображаются на экране). Деревья DOM и CSSOM входят в общее дерево BOM. 
Когда я пишу разметку, то для *читабельнотсти* я ее форматирую – делаю табуляцию, пробелы могу поставить и переводы строк *между элементами*. Эти табуляции, пробелы и переводы строк браузер и перегоняет в текстовые узлы DOM. Например, если я напишу такой код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><style>.qq{width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;}</style></head><body><div class="qq" id="first">1</div><div class="qq" id="second">2</div></body></html>
```

То есть, код *без табуляций и переводов строк*, то эти загадочные текстовые объекты-узлы дерева DOM *исчезнут* (если взять, например, и посмотреть «более упорядоченный» объект-список объектов-узлов-детей объекта-узла body из кода выше, то там будет только два объекта div, а текстовых объектов-узлов уже не будет). Но такой код нечитабельный совсем, поэтому надо их либо удалять, либо задавать им font-size:0px. Плюс, еще надо помнить, что, если у меня объект-узел является inline-block, то он подчиняется *законам строк* – этот объект рассматривается *как буква*. Например, у него появляется верхний отступ межстрочный, и, чтобы его убрать, надо написать line-height:0px.

Comment: Постарайтесь описать лаконичнее и без воды и капса.

Comment: я не писатель. как получилось - так и получилось. воды тут нет. объяснено на пальцах, чтобы любой человек понял, а не только спец. а спецам здесь делать нечего - они и так все знают

Comment: Кем бы я не был - такой длинный, сухой, невыразительный, скачущий из-за капса текст я читать не буду, как, наверняка, большинство из заходящих сюда.

Comment: да мне все равно. не нравится вам, как написано - не читайте. никто не заставляет читать эту статью - есть куча других. по себе о других не судите.   если человеку не понятно что-то, он любой текст прочитает, если информация толковая.  наведением марафета (чтобы все выглядело с иголочки) на сайте пусть занимаются те, кто на нем деньги зарабатывает.

Comment: Если Вам всё равно как писать ответ, вам нечего делать на этом поприще. Пишете-то Вы для читателей.

Comment: я пишу, чтобы человек разобрался, а не для того, чтобы любовался. если нравится вам - можете свои ответы до идеала доводить в плане внешнего вида. я на куче форумов зарегистрирован и не буду тратить время, чтобы на каждом форуме свой вопрос до идеального внешнего вида доводить. если вам нравится на это тратить время - это ваш выбор. тут нет никакого "поприща" - это просто форум. пришел, информацию получил, что-то сам подсказал и ушел

Answer (score 0):

часто сталкивался с таким поведением inline-block, мое решение не очень приятное визуально, все div с inline-block пишутся в одну строку.
а именно закрывающий тег должен быть в одной строке и без пробела с последующим открывающим.

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="images">
 </div><div class="images">
 </div>
 <div class="images">
 </div><div class="images">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: это решает только боковой пропуск. межстрочный остается

Comment: забавность я даже не замечал, спасибо за заметку на будущие

Comment: vertical-align:top; для .images и отступ пропадает